# Disable swap file from the Linux kernel boot parameters

Tags: swap

I am thinking of installing linux-lts as a backup kernel to use temporarily if mainline breaks (I'm on Arch). I use a swap file under Btrfs and that's not supported on Linux <5.0. Anyway to disable swap file with kernel boot parameters or some other way before systemd mounts the swap file reading off the fstab?

Comment: Not to write it in the fstab?

Comment: Both kernels would use the same fstab, so that wouldnt be a reliable solution because I would need to edit fstab everytime I go to linux LTS, which I would only be using if I couldnt boot from the main kernel

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of kernel parameters:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Some parameters customize the resume but no parameter disables swap at all.